# How to save user data to database instead of a pickle or a json file when trying to post videos on YouTube using Django and data v3 api

Tags: django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, pickle, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to upload videos to youtube using Django and MSSQL, I want to store the user data to DB so that I can log in from multiple accounts and post videos.

The official documentation provided by youtube implements a file system and after login, all the user data gets saved there, I don't want to store any data in a file as saving files to DB would be a huge risk and not a good practice. So how can I bypass this step and save data directly to DB and retrieve it when I want to post videos to a specific account?

In short, I want to replace the pickle file implementation with storing it in the database.

Here's my code

```
def youtubeAuthenticate():
        os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"
        api_service_name = "youtube"
        api_version = "v3"
        client_secrets_file = "client_secrets.json"
        creds = None
        # the file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time
        if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
            with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)
        # if there are no (valid) credentials availablle, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # save the credentials for the next run
            with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)

        return build(api_service_name, api_version, credentials=creds)

@api_view(['GET','POST'])   
def postVideoYT(request):

    youtube = youtubeAuthenticate()
 
    print('yt',youtube)
    try:
        initialize_upload(youtube, request.data)
    except HttpError as e:
        print("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))

    return Response("Hello")


def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
    

    print('options', options)
    print("title", options['title'])
    # tags = None
    # if options.keywords:
    #     tags = options.keywords.split(",")

    body=dict(
        snippet=dict(
        title=options['title'],
        description=options['description'],
        tags=options['keywords'],
        categoryId=options['categoryId']
        ),
        status=dict(
        privacyStatus=options['privacyStatus']
        )
    )

#   # Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.

    insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
        part=",".join(body.keys()),
        body=body,

        media_body=MediaFileUpload(options['file'], chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
    )

    path = pathlib.Path(options['file'])
    ext = path.suffix
    getSize = os.path.getsize(options['file'])
    resumable_upload(insert_request,ext,getSize)

# This method implements an exponential backoff strategy to resume a
# failed upload.
def resumable_upload(insert_request, ext, getSize):
  response = None
  error = None
  retry = 0
  

  while response is None:
        try:
            print("Uploading file...")
            status, response = insert_request.next_chunk()
            if response is not None:
                    respData = response
                    if 'id' in response:
                    print("Video id '%s' was successfully uploaded." % response['id'])
                        
                    else:
                        exit("The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s" % response)
        except HttpError as e:
            if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
                error = "A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status,
                                                                    e.content)
            else:
                        raise
        except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS as e:
            error = "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e

        if error is not None:
            print(error)
            retry += 1
            if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
                exit("No longer attempting to retry.")

        max_sleep = 2 ** retry
        sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
        print("Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying..." % sleep_seconds)
        time.sleep(sleep_seconds)
```

Comment: What have you tried?  There are a lot of questions on stack with how to save a file to the database with Django   I just did a search on How to store token pickle in database and found this strait off https://stackoverflow.com/q/32651965/1841839

Comment: The thing is I don't want to store any files, instead, I want a workaround so that I can store the user credentials in DB and access them when I want to upload a video to that specific account

Comment: Im not saying store the file.  I am saying take the object that is returned and rather then storing it as a file.  Store the full json string in your database.  You dont need to save it as a file anywhere.  Its just an object just put it directly into a column in the database and load it back.   **INSERT INTO pickleTest VALUES (NULL, 'testCred', %s)""", (pickledCreds, ))**

Comment: Ok, got it, thank you for the suggestion however, is there a way to replace youtubeAuthenicate() completely and also implement OAuth login. Is it possible?

Comment: Authorization and Authentication (login) are two different things.    Your app requesting authorization to access the users data when they are offline.    Your not trying to Authenticate the user who is currently behind the machine at this moment.